# Split Text and reorganize and concatenate back together

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, concatenate

I want a formula to split data "052 089652" and to reorganize it as "089652/A052/9" in Google Sheets. The formula needs to add "A" to the start of "052", add a "9" at the end, keep the leading zero, if there is one and place "/" in between. Another example below:

Input: `125 896542`

Output:`896542/A125/9`

I can do it using SPLIT and CONCATENATE functions in different cells but it gets messy.

Is there a simpler "all in one formula" to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming You provided a exact format of data,

```
=REGEXREPLACE(F2,"(\d+) (\d+)", "$2/A$1/9")
```

Comment: That's great, is there a similar formula for excel. as regexreplace doesn't work in excel. Sorry didn't mention that in the original post but noticed this might need recreating in excel.